# Building histogram of latency using sample of input data

Tags: statistics, sampling

Assume I have input data set consisting of a web page response time. I'd like to build histogram from input data, but for practical reasons I can only use sample of data. Based on histogram I want to answer question: what is 99.99 percentile response time?
Input data does not follow normal distribution, it is most likely bi-modal or multi-modal.

Question is: how large sample do I need? Can I estimate error somehow? Is picking every X element of input data good strategy for sampling?

Comment: Can you at least have a computer order your dataset from smallest to largest latency?

Comment: No, dataset is not ordered. If it was, then simply picking every X item would give exact answer.

Comment: No, it wouldn't. You'd simply pick let $\hat p_{.9999}=x_{(\lfloor.9999\times N\rfloor)}$. Thanks for the clarification though. I'll post a method and its error in a sec.

Comment: Could you please explain why wouldn't it? Let's say I need percentiles 1..100, then X = N/100 and getting every X element gives percentiles 1..100. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend calculating a non-parametric confidence interval for the 99.99th percentile. A good explanation is given [here](https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat414/node/317).

For statistical accuracy, you should do random sampling with replacement. Take as large a sample as possible $(n\gg 20)$ and use the normal approximation to the binomial mentioned in the link to find the order statistics (in your sample) that correspond (as closely as possible) to your desired confidence level.

Comment: Thanks for the link, this is pretty cool!